# Testing a Buildroot external package fails on a defconfig entry

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, buildroot

I'm trying to add an `br2-external` package to a `Buildroot` build for a `sama5d4_xplained` board. I'm testing it using the `utils/test-pkg` utility and with every toolchain it fails on `BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_9=y`, according to the `missing.config` file. It's an entry in the `sama5d4_xplained_defconfig`, which is used in the build.

I attempted to find what does the option mean in the manual and by googling, but any information is nowhere to be found. It doesn't seem to be related to the version of kernel headers installed on my machine, since my headers are `4.15`.

The exact command used is:

```
./utils/test-pkg -c ../../config/sama5d4_xplained_defconfig -p {package}
```

The `sama5d4_xplained_defconfig` has the problematic entry:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_9=y
```

`logfile` content:

```
#
# configuration written to /home/bartlomiej/br-test-pkg/br-arm-full-static/.config
#
Value requested for BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_9 not in final .config
Requested value:  BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_9=y
Actual value:     

Using support/config-fragments/autobuild/br-arm-full-static.config as base
Merging support/config-fragments/minimal.config
Merging ../../config/sama5d4_xplained_defconfig
  GEN     /home/bartlomiej/br-test-pkg/br-arm-full-static/Makefile
#
# configuration written to /home/bartlomiej/br-test-pkg/br-arm-full-static/.config
#
Value requested for BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_9 not in final .config
Requested value:  BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_9=y
Actual value:     

Using support/config-fragments/autobuild/br-arm-full-static.config as base
Merging support/config-fragments/minimal.config
Merging ../../config/sama5d4_xplained_defconfig
  GEN     /home/bartlomiej/br-test-pkg/br-arm-full-static/Makefile
#
# configuration written to /home/bartlomiej/br-test-pkg/br-arm-full-static/.config
#
Value requested for BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_9 not in final .config
Requested value:  BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_9=y
Actual value:
```

What does this entry mean, and what do I do to fix the build problems?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a configuration file that enables just your package. With recent Buildroot, you can also use `test-pkg -p <pkg>` without `-c` option.

`test-pkg` will do a build-test of one or more packages with a collection of different toolchains (by default, a subset of the toolchains used for [the autobuilders](http://autobuild.buildroot.org)). The configuration file you supply with `-c` is supposed to select the package(s) that you want to test. Any toolchain that does not satisfy the dependencies of those packages will be skipped.

The board defconfigs (like `sama5d4_xplained_defconfig`) build a toolchain as part of their configuration. This toolchain *always* differs from the toolchains used in the autobuilders. Therefore, if you supply one of the defconfigs as the `-c` option, all toolchains will always be skipped.

However, if you are only interested in the sama5d4 Xplained board, there is no real need to use test-pkg to test your package with all toolchains. Just enable the package to a custom configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I misunderstood the purpose of `test-pkg` - I thought of it as of a convenient way to test a package without having to go through the whole buildroot build process. It turned out that my package builds properly for the board-specific toolchains and the toolchains used in `test-pkg` didn't make any sense for the boards I'm interested in.